# stroking or stroke

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading National Geographic magazine, this is paragraph:

> To a lobster couple, this is normal sex: For days the female squirts urine into the den of her desired mate. Beguiled by the scent, he lets her move in. Foreplay—stroking each other with antennae and with feet covered in taste receptors—lasts several days.

Question:

Why here is stroking instead of stroke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an apposition. Two nouns (or noun phrases next to one another). a short example would be "My brother, a teacher, enjoys his work"  The nouns "My brother and "a teacher" are in apposition. It means "my brother, who is a teacher..." or "The teacher who is my brother..."

The phrase "stroking each other..." is a noun phrase, and the verb "stroking" is a gerund. This noun phrase is in apposition to "foreplay". So it means "Foreplay, which consists of stroking each other...". The function of the clause is to be a noun, and so a gerund has been used. The gerund form of "stroke" is "stroking".